# Redux connect() higherordercomponent not working while i pass action creater throwing mapDispatchToProps

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

Action creater not working in react-redux while using the mapDispatchToProps function return object to pass in connect HOC. It working while passing Action creater directly in connect HOC something below. Not able to understand the difference.

**Not Working:**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = () => {
        return {
            increment,
            decrement
        }
    }
   
const WrappedCounter = ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter);
```

**Working:**

```
const WrappedCounter = ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps, {
        increment,
        decrement
    })(Counter);
```

**Detailed Code:**

```
<script type="text/babel" data-plugins="proposal-class-properties" data-presets="env,react">
// Action Creators - You don't need to change these
const increment = () => ({ type: 'increment' });
const decrement = () => ({ type: 'decrement' });

const Counter = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button className="increment" onClick={props.increment}>Increment</button>
            <button className="decrement" onClick={props.decrement}>Decrement</button>
            Current Count: <span>{props.count}</span>
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { count: state.count }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = () => {
    return {
        increment,
        decrement
    }
}

const WrappedCounter = ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter);

// Only change code *before* me!
// -----------

const store = Redux.createStore(Redux.combineReducers({
    count: (count = 0, action) => {
        if (action.type === 'increment') {
            return count + 1;
        } else if (action.type === 'decrement') {
            return count - 1;
        } else {
            return count;
        }
    }
}));

ReactDOM.render(
    <ReactRedux.Provider store={store}>
        <WrappedCounter />
    </ReactRedux.Provider>, 
    document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [two valid syntaxes](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#two-forms-of-mapdispatchtoprops) for writing `mapDispatchToProps`. What you have here is kind of a combination of the two, but it's not correct for either one.

#### [Function Syntax](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-a-function)

The "classic" (largely outdated) form of `mapDispatchToProps` is a function which takes `dispatch` as an argument and returns props of your component.  Those props are just normal functions so they need to make the `dispatch` call themselves.

It is very verbose and I don't recommend this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    increment: () => dispatch(increment()),
    decrement: () => dispatch(decrement())
  }
}
```

#### [Object Syntax](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object)

The simpler way to define `mapDispatchToProps` is with the object shorthand notation.  Here, you return a dictionary of action creator functions and react-redux handles binding them to `dispatch` automatically.

That looks like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  increment,
  decrement
}
```

When using this syntax, `mapDispatchToProps` **is not a function, it's just an object.**

In your semi-working solution where you defined `mapDispatchToProps` as a function and then called the function with `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps())(Counter)`, you using this syntax but with an extra step.  You defined a function that returns the object.  Then called the function to get the object.

#### Just Use Hooks

The most modern way of writing this is to ditch the `connect` higher-order component entirely and use the react-redux hooks.

```
const Counter = () => {
    const count = useSelector((state) => state.count);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return (
        <div>
            <button className="increment" onClick={() => dispatch(increment())}>Increment</button>
            <button className="decrement" onClick={() => dispatch(decrement())}>Decrement</button>
            Current Count: <span>{props.count}</span>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Endorsed 1000% :)

Answer (score 0):

The Below solution is working, while i call the function

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return { count: state.count }
    }
    
    const mapDispatchToProps = () => {
        return {
            increment,
            decrement
        }
    }
   
const WrappedCounter = ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps())(Counter);
```

but still i have doubt

for state I'm declaring and plased in HOC connect it working but mapDispatchToProps is  not working without calling it.

`mapStateToProps` // just passing in HOC

`mapDispatchToProps()` // here I'm passing and Calling the function